# How to add locale into the Facebook Registration Plugin via iframe

Tags: facebook, registration

I'm using Facebook Registration plugin via iframe and I tried to change the form language using locale parameter:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=650161075012011&locale='spa_EC'&
         redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
         fields=[
                  {'name':'name'},
                  {'name':'email'},
                 {'name':'location'},
                 {'name':'birthday'},
                 {'name':'phone','description':'Phone Number','type':'text'}
                ]"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
      height="330">
</iframe>
```

But it did not work, what is the correct way to change the language of always using the iframe form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The locale parameter you've entered `spa_EC` is not valid since there is no `spa` language code in [iso639-2 standard](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php).

also there shouldn't be surrounded by quote marks. `&locale='spa_EC'`

from Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/)

> pass the locale parameter set to be a POSIX locale, which is a 2
>   letter [lowercase language code](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) then an _ followed by a 2 letter
>   uppercase country code.

So it should be `&locale=es_EC`.